# Create a bunch of tables into a main table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok i'm going to try to explain what I need.
I am making a browsergame in which players have some animals that they can enroll for a competition.
But every day there is a new competition.

What I have in mind:
A main table 
**competitions**
with subtables
competion 1
results of that competition
competion 2
results of that competition
competion 3
results of that competition

Is this possible or am i thinking in a wrong way.

Comment: I would love to answer, but your grammar is very confusing!

Comment: _Is this possible or am i thinking in a wrong way_ You are thinking in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of it the wrong way.

You want to have one table competitions that has one row for each competition.  It would have columns such as CompetitionID, DateOfCompetition, and so on.

You should have another table, CompetitionResults, that would have the results from any competition.  This could have CompetitionId, AnimalId, Results.

You should have a table called Animals, so you can keep track of the animals, and perhaps one called owners.

In any case, SQL does not have the idea of "subtables".  It has the idea of entities and relationships.  You should do some research on this topic and try to apply it to this domain.